# run script from command line and pass String array

Tags: powershell

So basically I need to run my ps1 script from command line and pass my custom arguments into my script. My script expects a String array, but when I run the command, I get an error that a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'X1'

This is my command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MyScript.ps1" -builds "X1” “X2" "X3" "X4"
```

My understanding is it knows what to do with the first parameter 'X1' but not the second and so it crashes? Any ideas whay?

Comment: I'm not familar with powershell and I don't know your script -properbly you should post it here- must not the elements seperated with colon, like "X1,X2,X3,.."?

Comment: doesn't make a difference with the comma or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-Command` parameter instead of the `-File` parameter. Notice the change in behavior from the screenshot below, and the sample script.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [int[]] $MyInts
)

foreach ($MyInt in $MyInts) {
    $MyInt + 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have known. I gotta figure something out since a RunScript in TFS 2013 uses the -File and not -Command. Ill need to modify my ps1 script to recognize the commas and create the string array in there.

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite explain why `-file` is not working but that parameter has other known issues.  When you use it you don't get a proper exit code from PowerShell. Using `-command` does work:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "& {& 'C:\Program Files\MSBuild\myscript.ps1' -builds x1,x2,x3}"
```